# DataTables ajax.reload when keeping pagination it jumps to the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables with ajax sourced data.
I have to keep the data up to date every 30 seconds without refreshing the page, and `ajax.reload()` is the function that I need.

I put `ajax.reload()` inside a `setInterval` function.

And all works right (if you stay on page 1). But when you surf the table on page 2 or 3, when `setInterval` is fired, it gets you back to the page 1.

So ...
Looking to docs at this url: http://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

if I pass "false" as second parameter it holds the current paging position, and paging is not reset on reload. BINGO!

It works! BUT ... I have a new problem that a tried to solve the all day and now I'm stuck. That's why I post this question.

It keeps paging but if you are not on page 1, every time that `ajax.reload()` is fired, the page scrolls (jump directly) to the bottom.

It's very unfriendly, unreadable, unusable. 
I don't know WHY the page scrolls to the end-bottom.

I post a link to my simple datatable js that I use on my page.
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uwjr5r5m/)

```
        var url = table.data('url');
        var filterType = table.data('filtertype');

        var options = {
            "ajax": {
                "url": url,
                "type": "GET",
                "data": function (d) {
                    d.contact_type = filterType
                    // this variable will set by server when page load. It should be "lead", "prospect", "client". Leave empty to get all.
                }
            },
            "columns": [
                {"data": "html_is_company"},
                {"data": "name"},
                {"data": "html_type_label"},
                {"data": "created"},
                {"data": "last_update"},
                {"data": "html_actions"},
                {"data": "tsu"},
                {"data": "business_name"}
            ],
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "pageLength": 20,
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
            "columnDefs": [
                {
                    "targets": [ 7 ],
                    "visible": false,
                    "searchable": true,
                },
                {
                    "targets": [ 6, 7 ],
                    "searchable": false,
                    "visible": false
                },
                {
                    "targets": [0, 5],
                    "searchable": false,
                    "orderable": false
                },
                {
                    "targets": [ 4 ],
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {
                        return moment(data, IN_DATE_TIME_FORMAT, 'it').fromNow();//.format(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);////;
                    }
                },
                {
                // Sort column 4 (formatted date) by column 6 (hidden seconds)
                    "orderData":[ 6 ],
                    "targets": [ 4 ]
                }],
            "order": [[4, "desc"]],
            "search": "_INPUT_",
            "language": {
                "sSearchPlaceholder": "Cerca...",
                "paginate": {
                    "previous": '<i class="icon wb-chevron-left-mini"></i>',
                    "next": '<i class="icon wb-chevron-right-mini"></i>'
                },
                //"url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.9/i18n/Italian.json"
            }
      };

      var datatable = table.DataTable(options);
      this.setDataTable(datatable);

      setInterval(function(){
        datatable.ajax.reload(null, false);
      }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
"fnDrawCallback": function(data) {
    $(".paginate_button > a").on("focus", function() {
        $(this).blur();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

jacopo.galli's solution was very clunky when I implemented for my table, but it's probably because my code was a mess. The idea of adding blur() is great thou.

I rewrite his code a bit:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".paginate_button > a").blur();
});
```

The buttons on the pagination bar will be "unfocused" once the page scrolls.
So your final code should look like this:

```
var url = table.data('url');
    var filterType = table.data('filtertype');

    var options = {
        "ajax": {
            "url": url,
            "type": "GET",
            "data": function (d) {
                d.contact_type = filterType
                // this variable will set by server when page load. It should be "lead", "prospect", "client". Leave empty to get all.
            }
        },
        "columns": [
            {"data": "html_is_company"},
            {"data": "name"},
            {"data": "html_type_label"},
            {"data": "created"},
            {"data": "last_update"},
            {"data": "html_actions"},
            {"data": "tsu"},
            {"data": "business_name"}
        ],
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "pageLength": 20,
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [ 7 ],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": true,
            },
            {
                "targets": [ 6, 7 ],
                "searchable": false,
                "visible": false
            },
            {
                "targets": [0, 5],
                "searchable": false,
                "orderable": false
            },
            {
                "targets": [ 4 ],
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    return moment(data, IN_DATE_TIME_FORMAT, 'it').fromNow();//.format(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);////;
                }
            },
            {
            // Sort column 4 (formatted date) by column 6 (hidden seconds)
                "orderData":[ 6 ],
                "targets": [ 4 ]
            }],
        "order": [[4, "desc"]],
        "search": "_INPUT_",
        "language": {
            "sSearchPlaceholder": "Cerca...",
            "paginate": {
                "previous": '<i class="icon wb-chevron-left-mini"></i>',
                "next": '<i class="icon wb-chevron-right-mini"></i>'
            },
            //"url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.9/i18n/Italian.json"
        }
  };

  var datatable = table.DataTable(options);
  this.setDataTable(datatable);

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".paginate_button > a").blur();
  });

  setInterval(function(){
    datatable.ajax.reload(null, false);
  }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution that works for me.

The problem was the "focus" on DataTables pagination links.

When user clicks on a link page, it sets a focus on that link and when `ajax.reload()` is fired the browser gets you where the focused element is. My table is the last element of the page so the page scrolls to the bottom.

I got it when I clicked on another area of the page after clicked on page 2 link. The "jumping" problem was gone.

So, I solved firing a `blur()` when DataTables has complete its initialization and when `ajax.reload()` has finished (thanks to the first parameter that allows you to define a function).

In DataTables options I added this:

```
"initComplete": function(settings, json) {
                $(".paginate_button > a").on("focus", function(){
                    $(this).blur();
                });
            },
```

and then, in `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(function(){
          datatable.ajax.reload(function(){
              $(".paginate_button > a").on("focus", function(){
                  $(this).blur();
              });
          }, false);
      }, 30000);
```

Don't know if this is the "best solution" ... but it works and could helps someone.